# iOS Cordova app crashes on Resume

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm building a Cordova app with a plugin for the Magtek uDynamo card reader. It crashes when I resume.

The app works fine if I never call the card reader (or never pause/resume).

I used the Zombie Profiler, and this is the error message- An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'MTSCRA' object (zombie) at address: 0x17522260.

I checked that I am using ARC and put logging statements all through out my native plugin code to make sure the MTSCRA object is never NULL. Crash dump didn't give any backtrace, and the exception breakpoint landed in machine code.

I'm still very new at iOS/Cordova, so please let me know if there are any other debugging tools I can use or if I should post some code to help diagnose the problem.

EDIT: Adding additional info in response to comments below

Here's the flow- 
1. run card reader page 
2. open page w/o card reader (card reader is disconnected) 
3. pause, resume 
4. finish working on page w/o card reader 
5. redirected to page with card reader (card reader is supposed to connect) 
6. crash

Comment: I will try to make a guess. You have mentioned `step 5.Redirected to page with card reader`. Have you created the plugin yourself or it is a third party plugin? Are the pages two distinct pages or they are a single page app. What I mean is the redirected page a separate HTML page with the card reader script. If yes, then your scripts contained in the redirected page will not work, according to my limited knowledge. This is not something related to Phonegap but Web App in general. What you could do is create a mock up of the card reader, like a virtual card reader to test the app and plugin.

Comment: I suspect that your card reader is causing a problem on re-entry (eg. to its page). Make sure the objects on that page are being destroyed before re-visiting (assuming it instantiates each page load), or add a check to see if the objects are already instantiated before proceeding on re-entry.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Cordova, but I would put a check on that object for nil before you try and use it. When you app goes to the background, you should disconnect from the card reader and on resume reconnect.

Comment: I added logs to check if the object is nil before using it. It was never nil in my plugin code before crashing.


It crashes even if I'm pausing/resuming from a page without the card reader. Here's the flow- 
1. run card reader page 
2. open page w/o card reader (card reader is disconnected)
3. pause, resume
4. finish working on page w/o card reader
5. redirected to page with card reader (card reader is supposed to connect)
6. crash